# Find correspondences of nodes between two graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I have two graphs (actually two street maps, one very fine grained and exact, the other coarser and maybe a bit faulty w.r.t. the nodes coordinates and the topology) and I want to find corresponding nodes and or edges between those two graphs. The nodes in the graph have a location in a global map (but the locations might differ a bit between corresponding nodes in the two graphs). Is there some standard approximation algorithm for that problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is also known as the network alignment problem. Here is an example algorithm for dealing with this problem: [GHOST](https://github.com/rob-p/GHOST/blob/master/UserGuide.md)

More details can be found in this bachelor's thesis:[Survey on the Graph Alignment Problem and a Benchmark of
Suitable Algorithms](https://www.informatik.hu-berlin.de/de/forschung/gebiete/wbi/teaching/studienDiplomArbeiten/finished/2013/doepmann_ba_final.pdf)